# Connecting RaspberryPi to the network the static way

Tags: networking, static-ip

I want to set up the networks on my raspberry, I tried to do it the `static` way:

I opened a terminal on the pi, wrote:

[image: what I did]

That is to say, I wrote static instead of what was written before (which was not dhcp if remember). And wrote down address, gateway and netmask only changing the two last digits of the adress from the one I had written on my computer.

Yet, when I try to ping the given adress I receive no response...

```
:~$ ping 192.168.0.29
PING 192.168.0.29 (192.168.0.29) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.0.35 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.35 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.35 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
^C
--- 192.168.0.29 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, +3 errors, 100% packet loss, time 3016ms
pipe 3
```

Comment: You have set the wired eth0 connection to be static.  Is that what you intended? Or are you trying to set a static wlan0 (wireless) address?

Comment: @joan no, I'm looking for a wired connection therefore a wired address I assume.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was found at [pihw.wordpress.com](https://pihw.wordpress.com/guides/direct-network-connection/), all I had to do was

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 the.add.ress.togive
```

If you have better answer I would accept then, else I would answer my own question

Comment: Also, e.g., `ip addr add x.x.x.x/24 dev eth0`, since as per the man page `ifconfig` should be considered "obsolete" on linux.  However, I am sure it will continue to be viable into perpetuity anyway.  Beware to use a [CIDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing) suffix (`/24` or `/16`) with `ip addr` or it defaults to `/32`, which is probably not useful in most circumstances.

Comment: There is no need to be coy about your IP address. The addresses are private and not routable outside your network.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in `/etc/network/interfaces` you need to add the information immediately after the eth0 declaration, e.g.

```
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.0.29
gateway 192.168.0.254
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

---

EDITED TO ADD

As pointed out by @milliways this answer is wrong if dhcpd is enabled (the default for jessie).

Comment: This does not work in Jessie, unless you disable `dhcpcd`. (actually it does allocate an address, but so does `dhcpcd` leaving an indeterminate state).

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of allocating static IP addresses. You don't mention which OS you are using.

See [How do I set up networking/WiFi/Static IP](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697) for a tutorial for latest Raspbian.

Answer (score 0):

you can either add
`denyinterfaces eth0` to /etc/dhcpcd.conf and configure it with `/etc/network/interfaces`

**or**

`#Static IP Block
interface eth0
static ip_address=192.168.0.200/24
static routers=192.168.0.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.0.1`

http://sizious.com/2015/08/28/setting-a-static-ip-on-raspberry-pi-on-raspbian-20150505/